# Question on XSLT following-sibling

Tags: xslt

My XML structure looks like this

```
<COMPANY>
<COMPANY-DATA>ABC</COMPANY-DATA>
<ID>10800</ISSUE-ID>
<PROJECT-ID/>
</COMPANY-ISSUE-INFO>
 </COMPANY>
"COMPANY Node repeats"
```

What I want to do is I want to do I want to check for COMPANY-DATA='ABC' and get its ID

I tried using

```
<xsl:value-of select="//COMPANY-DATA/.='ABC'/following-sibling::ID/."/>
```

But this doesn't seem to work and throwing error

> Expression must evaluate to node-set
>   //COMPANY-DATA/.= -->'ABC'<--
>   /following-sibling::ID/.

Thanks,

Karthik

Edit: I found the solution

```
 **<xsl:value-of select="//COMPANY-DATA[.='ABC']/following-sibling::ID/."/>**
```

Thanks

Comment: Expression must evaluate to node-set //COMPANY-DATA/.= -->'ABC'<-- /following-sibling::ID/.

Comment: OK. I got it <xsl:value-of select="//COMPANY-DATA[.='ABC']/following-sibling::ID/."/>

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question.

Comment: @Alejandro: i don't see any link to mark as answer

Comment: You must add an answer first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="//COMPANY-DATA[.='ABC']/following-sibling::ID/."/>
```

Comment: this only works, if the id element is always the element after the company-data element

Answer (score 1):

The first thing i noticed ist, that whe snipped you postet is no valid XML. The Element `<ID>` is closed by the End-Element `</ISSUED_ID>` and there is a single closing Element `</COMPANY-ISSUE-INFO>`

But if i get you right, you want to find the ID of the `<COMPANY>` Element where the `<COMPANY-DATA>` is ABC. So your Comment on your question should do this. But you could also use

```
<xsl:value-of select="//COMPANY[COMPANY-DATA='ABC']/ID"/>
```

This removes the need of having the Comapny-Data and ID in a specific sequence.